# Database design: different fields for multiple user types

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am building an application using MySQL 5.0.77 that contains

a) different user types (e.g. carpenter, mechanic, ..., plumber)
b) different input fields for each user type, e.g. user selects carpenter and is presented with fields pertaining to that profession, where the fields for each profession are different

My thinking is along the lines of:

`Table: users

user_id

user_name`

`Table: carpentry

user_id

woodwork_rating

metalwork_rating`

`Table: plumbing

user_id

central_heating_rating

bathroom_rating`

And so on...

This does not seem very good though since I could potentially end up with lots of tables and users existing in multiple tables with different fields.

I quite like the idea of a metatags table (like we see in Wordpress) so that each users field entry is stored, e.g.

`Table: user_info

user_id

field

value`

So we would have for example

1 | woodwork_rating | intermediate
1 | metalwork_rating | advanced
2 | woodowork_rating | advanced

My question is, **how would you structure a database that has multiple fields for multiple users for which each user only fills in one category of the available fields?**

Thanks

Comment: I think, what you're asking, is how do you stop the following from happening:

1 | woodwork_rating | intermediate;
1 | woodwork_rating | advanced;
2 | woodowork_rating | advanced;

The problem being that there is now no way to tell which woodwork_rating to use for user 1.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Users:

```
 UserID: Autoinc PRIMARY KEY
 (More user data columns here)
 UserType: CHAR(5)
```

Table UserTypes

```
 UserType: CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
 Description: VARCHAR(50)
```

Table UserRatingList

```
 UserRatingCode: CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
 UserType: CHAR(5) REFERENCES UserTypes
 Description: VARCHAR(50)
```

Table UserRatings

```
 UserID: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY / REFERENCES Users
 UserRatingCode: CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY / REFERENCES UserRatingList
 Rating: INTEGER (or whatever you prefer)
```

The table UserRatingList establishes the pattern of ratings that can be applied to each user type.  UserRatings contains the actual ratings.  I use CHAR(5) to provider readable codes without having to join in the Description fields, but you can change them to INTEGER if you want.

This structure can also be adapted to allow each user to have multiple types; simply create an addition UserTypeLinks table with UserID and UserType.

Comment: This makes sense although I realise my question was misleading. Not all of the user fields will be ratings, although I think this would work if I change UserRatingList to UserMetaList or something and UserRatings to UserMeta.

Comment: Yes, it's always more complex in practice than in theory.  Exactly how I would structure the more complex database depends on what that additional meta-data looked like (and you might choose a somewhat different design than I would).  The important thing to take away from my answer (if anything) is to avoid the design that adds a column to some table for every new rating.  Instead, use a design that adds a _row_ to one or more tales for each new rating type (or meta type) you create.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to rely on 'mike' s last answer. 
i am facing this exact problem. i am creating a network with the following types

```
Enterprise {name, mail, adress, etc ...}
Employee {name, mail, branch, jobdescription, etc ...}
Individual {name, mail, surname, age, town, etc...}
```

how about:

Table Users

```
userID (autoincr)
userType
mailadress
password
...
```

Table Usertypes

```
typeID
typeName
typeDescr
```

Table Enterprises

```
entID (autoincr)
userID
field 1
field 2
...
```

Table Employee

```
empID (autoincr)
userID
...
```

Table Individuals

```
indID (autoincr)
userID
...
```

does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Are all the fields going to be "ratings" with the same datatype? If so I like Larry Lustig's solution.

Or could there be unrelated fields with different data types?  dates, strings, decimals, integers? If so, the first solution of having 1 to 1 related tables that join with Users is OK. As long as you don't need to dynamically add new fields at run time.